# Função dando valores errados

Tags: c

Por algum motivo, minha função de calcular distâncias está dando valores errados à vezes. Não só isso, mas os valores parecem ser de endereços de memória (pois são muito grandes), mas não tenho certeza se é isso.
A função:

```
float distancia(int ax, int ay, int bx, int by) // Calcula a distancia entre dois pontos, onde eh respectivamente (X1 Y1), (X2 Y2)
{
    return(sqrt((pow((ax - bx), 2)) + (pow((ay - by), 2))));  
}
```

Uma das funções que chama a função acima. Ela escreve em um documento txt e os valores impresos lá saem errado:

```
void arquivoDistancia(float matrizDistancia[][30])
{
    FILE *aquivoDeSaida;
    int cont = 0, cont2 = 0;

    aquivoDeSaida = fopen("distancia.txt", "w");
    while( cont < 30 ) //loop para gravar os dados no arquivo.
    {
        while( cont2 < 30 ) //loop para gravar os dados no arquivo.
        {   
           fprintf(aquivoDeSaida, "%.2f ", matrizDistancia[cont][cont2]); //grava garacter a caracter no arquivo apontado por custo.
           cont2++;      
        }
        fprintf(aquivoDeSaida, "\n");
        cont++;
        cont2 = 0;      
    }
    fclose(aquivoDeSaida); 


}
```

e essa é a função que faz a matrizDistancia[][30]. Reparem que eu até coloquei um printf para ver os valores. O problema começa aqui pelo jeito. Ele imprime tudo certo no começo mas depois começa a aparecer números estranhos

```
void mDistancia(char cidadeXY[][150], int coordenadasX[], int coordenadasY[], float matrizDistancia[][30])
{
    int c, i, contadorC, contadorI;
    float dij; 

    for(i = 0, contadorI = 0; i < 30; i++, contadorI += 2)
    {
        for(c = 0, contadorC = 0; c < 30; c++, contadorC += 2)
        {
            dij = distancia(coordenadasX[contadorI], coordenadasY[contadorI], coordenadasX[contadorC], coordenadasY[contadorC]);
            printf("%.2f ", dij);
            matrizDistancia[i][c] = dij;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Você precisa aprender a debugar o código sozinha. Imprima o valor retornado por `distancia()` na tela, bem como seus parâmetros, e veja se eles fazem sentido. Depois de garantir que esta parte está OK, você se preocupa em grava os dados no arquivo.

Comment: Eu imprimi os valores. Inclusive mencionei isso na pergunta.

Comment: Eu vi. Os números "estranhos" são resultados do cálculo que você faz. Imprima também **os parâmetros** que estão sendo passados para `distancia()`, e ao encontrar um resultado "estranho" você vai ter condições de usar sua calculadora para verificar manualmente se o resultado faz sentido (ou não). Eu suspeito que o problema são os valores armazenados por `coordenadasX` e `coordenadasY`.

Comment: Beleza. Vou fazer isso. Imprimi os valores das coordenadas x e y e não são eles.

Comment: Ao calcular manualmente com esses valores, você detectou que o resultado de `distancia()` está correto quando eles são usados ou nesse momento o resultado já não faz mais sentido?

Comment: O resultado de distancia() não está correto. Só no começo que ele faz certinho. Depois começa a surgir valores errados bem grandes.

Comment: Você poderia exemplificar com valores de exemplo? Que números são passados para `distancia()` e qual valor ele retorna nesse caso?

Comment: @jane eu não programo em C, mas creio que seu problema seja com a precisão. Você deve tomar cuidado com os tipos numéricos pois eles são diferentes e podem te dar muita dor de cabeça. A resposta do **karlphillip** certamente vai te atender.

Answer (score 4):

É bom ter em mente que a assinatura de `sqrt()` informa que ele retorna um **double**. Ao tentar guardar seu resultado em uma variável **float** você poderá acabar perdendo informação, o que justificaria o problema que você observou.

Por outro lado, `sqrtf()` retorna um **float**, que seria mais apropriado no seu caso.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0, contadorI = 0; i < 30; i++, contadorI += 2)
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    for(c = 0, contadorC = 0; c < 30; c++, contadorC += 2)
    //                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        dij = distancia(coordenadasX[contadorI], coordenadasY[contadorI], coordenadasX[contadorC], coordenadasY[contadorC]);
```

Porque razao as variaveis `contadorI` e `contadorC` avancam de 2 em 2?

Desta forma nunca vais calcular as distancias entre pontos com indices impares; alem de que vais estar a aceder a elementos (provavelmente) inexistentes dos arrays.